# How to save and restore CR2-CR4 in ppc64le

Tags: powerpc

How to save and restore just the `CR2-CR4` registers in ppc64le assembly?

I am aware of mflr and mtlr instruction. But I want only `cr2-cr4`

Answer (score 2):

The `CRx` aren't actually registers, but 4-byte fields in a 32-byte register. You can get more details in the [Power ISA 2.07](https://openpowerfoundation.org/?resource_lib=ibm-power-isa-version-2-07-b) - see Section 2.3, page 30.

`mtlr`/`mflr` save and restore the link register, which is different: it's used for indirect branching.

You can save and restore individual CR fields with `mfocrf`/`mtocrf`: see Section 3.3.16.1, pg 112.

- `mfocrf r10,0x2` should save `CR2`
- `mfocrf r10,0x4` should save `CR3`
- `mfocrf r10,0x8` should save `CR4`
- and so on.

You could in theory do this in one go with a `mfcrf` (or the extended mnemonics `mtcr` and `mfcr`), but they are being phased out.